# Show correct model value even if error on field

Tags: model, wicket, validation

I have a Wicket TextField which displays a calculated value. The value is calculated in the get-method in the model object. I have attached a custom validator to the field.

My problem occurs when the validator fails. If I change some values in another fields, the calculated value should change in the failed field. This is not happening. I have verified that the get-metod is actually called, and it also calculates the correct value. However, it is not displayed in the text-field. The field is still showing the old one..

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When validation fails on a `FormComponent`, its `rawInput` isn't cleared - this is so that the user can fix the value, rather than having to enter everything from scratch.

In your case you are basically changing the model behind the `FormComponent`'s back so it doesn't know there is a new value. You should call the `modelChanged()` method on it after changing the model value - this will among other things reset validation and rawInput and then your form will work as expected.